# Does current flow from earth connected conductor in uniform electric field?

Tags: grounding, induction, inductive, electrostatic, conductors

If we place a conductor inside of uniform external electric field then opposite charges will get induced on the both sides of conductor.

What if we connect two earth wire to each side, will continuous current will flow through the conductor?

As from the positive charge induced side will take electron from ground and negative charge induced side will eject electron so will a continuous flow of current be seen in this case?[image]

Comment: it's not clear how your electric field's direction and your conductor's dimensions relate. Could you maybe add a drawing to clarify?

Comment: I have added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If we place a conductor inside of uniform external electric field then
> opposite charges will get induced on the both sides of conductor.*

At the point where the conductor begins on the left to where it ends on the right, the electric field inside the conductor is zero (a very good conductor). If the conductor isn't such a great conductor then there will be a small open circuit potential to be see but, if you try and short those sides out (via earth or just another conductor), that external short then causes the E-field insider to become close to zero.

You cannot transfer energy from a static electric field this way.

Comment: But the extra electrons is added from the ground and some electrons are released to the earth so this will cause again an induced internal electric field inside the conductor which will cause electron to drift in opposite of external electric field, so I am thinking this way

Comment: OK, I misread your comment so I'm deleting that. Electrons are not released to ground in any quantity more than they are taken from ground. In other words there is no net sink or source of electrons from ground. Forget ground and concentrate on someone applying a shorting conductor. Please also don't talk about ground and earth as separate entities here. As far as I can see they are the same thing.

Comment: Can you please explain how shorting by conductor will leads to E-field inside become zero

Comment: An electric field cannot exist if it is shorted out else there would be voltage produced that would cause a current flow in the shorting conductor. There is no available energy in a static field to be delivered.

Comment: @AniketKumar if we're done here you should [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to know what to do next.

Comment: @AniketKumar again, I say, if we're done here you should [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) to know what to do next. Repeated and clear avoidance of "playing the game" only ever results in people being unwilling to give you answers.